# converting date format to yyyy-mm-dd sql server c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, datetime

I am creating a web app in which i want to convert the date format into `yyyy-mm-dd`

currently i am getting date in the following format `Saturday, July 1, 2017`

here is my full select query

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY D.D_ID ) AS SL,
    D.D_DATE, D.USER_TP, D_ITEM_TYPE,D_AUTH_REF,D.D_ID, D.SUR_REFNO, D.REF_NO_DT,
    M.PART_NO,
    S.D_NAME,
    PART_DESC, DENOM, QTY_DEM, STORE_TYPE, ITEM_TYPE, EQUIPMENT,D_NO
FROM SURVEY_HDR D, DEMAND_STATUS S, STORE_MASTER M
WHERE 
    M.STORE_ID=D.PART_NO_ID
    AND S.D_ID=D.D_STATUS 
    AND D_DATE >= CONVERT(VarChar, 'Saturday, July 1, 2017',1)
    AND D_DATE <= CONVERT(VarChar, 'Monday, July 31, 2017',1)
ORDER BY D.D_ID
```

but i am getting the following error

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character string.

**NOTE**

D_DATE is in Date format and date is being stored as `'2011-01-01'`

how can i convert the date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string cannot be recognized as a date. Try this:

```
declare @mydate varchar(22) = 'Saturday, July 1, 2017'
select cast(substring(@mydate,charindex(',',@mydate)+2,22)as date)
```

Comment: Instead of hard-coding the length as **22**, `LEN(@mydate)` is fine, I guess.

Comment: @Arulkumar or len(@mydate)-charindex(',',@mydate)-1 if you want the right length. But 22 works fine, and i guess it will be 1ms faster.

Answer (score 0):

Why should you convert the date in sql? You can return it as datetime and then format in your web page using `toString`

Then in c# you can use:

```
  YourDateVar.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting String to date but first you have to parse it in date than format it as you want :
**Example:** 
1) Parse string to date :

```
DateTime _date;
string strDate = "";
_date = DateTime.Parse("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy"); // Saturday, July 1, 2017
```

2) Now convert this date to format you want :

```
strDate = _date.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd"); // YOUR CASE

strDate = _date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");   // 07/21/2017 
strDate = _date.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy");   //Saturday, 21 July 2017
strDate = _date.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm"); // Saturday, 21 July 2017 14:58
strDate = _date.ToString("HH:mm"); // 15:14
strDate = _date.ToString("hh:mm tt"); // 03:14 PM
strDate = _date.ToString("H:mm"); // 5:15
strDate = _date.ToString("h:mm tt"); // 3:16 PM
strDate = _date.ToString("HH:mm:ss"); // 15:16:29
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert both into the same format as "MM/dd/yyyy".

Change

```
CONVERT(VarChar, 'Saturday, July 1, 2017',1) To cast(SUBSTRING ( CONVERT(VarChar, 'Saturday, July 1, 2017',1) ,CHARINDEX ( ',',CONVERT(VarChar, 'Saturday, July 1, 2017',1) )+1 , Len(CONVERT(VarChar, 'Saturday, July 1, 2017',1)) ) as date)
```

and

```
CONVERT(VarChar, 'Monday, July 31, 2017',1) To cast(SUBSTRING ( CONVERT(VarChar, 'Monday, July 31, 2017',1) ,CHARINDEX ( ',',CONVERT(VarChar, 'Monday, July 31, 2017',1) )+1 , Len(CONVERT(VarChar, 'Monday, July 31, 2017',1)) ) as date)
```

And Here is your query

```
 SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY D.D_ID ) AS SL,
        D.D_DATE, D.USER_TP, D_ITEM_TYPE,D_AUTH_REF,D.D_ID, D.SUR_REFNO, D.REF_NO_DT,
        M.PART_NO,
        S.D_NAME,
        PART_DESC, DENOM, QTY_DEM, STORE_TYPE, ITEM_TYPE, EQUIPMENT,D_NO
    FROM SURVEY_HDR D, DEMAND_STATUS S, STORE_MASTER M
    WHERE 
        M.STORE_ID=D.PART_NO_ID
        AND S.D_ID=D.D_STATUS 
        AND Cast(D_DATE as Date) >= cast(SUBSTRING ( CONVERT(VarChar, 'Saturday, July 1, 2017',1) ,CHARINDEX ( ',',CONVERT(VarChar, 'Saturday, July 1, 2017',1) )+1 , Len(CONVERT(VarChar, 'Saturday, July 1, 2017',1)) ) as date)
        AND Cast(D_DATE as Date) <= cast(SUBSTRING ( CONVERT(VarChar, 'Monday, July 31, 2017',1) ,CHARINDEX ( ',',CONVERT(VarChar, 'Monday, July 31, 2017',1) )+1 , Len(CONVERT(VarChar, 'Monday, July 31, 2017',1)) ) as date)
    ORDER BY D.D_ID
```